# I made a plotly express choropleth_mapbox of US zip codes. Can I add a choropleth geometry that is the city boundary?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-express

Below is the code to create a choropleth_mapbox of Zip Codes, but in addition, I want to add another choropleth from a shapefile that is only the boundaries of the city

'''

```
zip_map_fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(zips, geojson=zip_map_zips, locations='Zip Code', 
                                color='price', 
                                range_color=(1, 5), 
                                featureidkey='properties.Zip Code',
                                center={'lat':mkt_lat, 'lon':mkt_long}, 
                                labels={'price' : 'Price'}, 
                                mapbox_style='carto-positron', 
                                color_continuous_scale='blues',
                                opacity=0.3, 
                                zoom=9,
                                hover_data=['Zip Code'])
zip_map_fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', visible=True)
```

'''

The map below works well for the Zip Codes, but all I want to do is add another line (an empty shape) that shows the outline of the whole city.

[image: Zip Code Choropleth]

I already have the shapefiles for the Zip Codes and the outline of the city.

I tried incorporating the city limit shapefile into the shapefile that is used to create the choropleth_mapbox, but it has no effect.

I know how to add a scattermapbox, but I just want to add another choropleth.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own problem for those that would like to do the same thing or something similar.  Here is what I did:

1. In the "zip_map_zps" parameter, which has all of the geometries for each Zip Code, I appended (added a row) the city limit geometry, and instead of associating it with a Zip Code, I just named it "city" in the Zip Code column.
2. In the "zips" parameter, I also appended a row to this DataFrame, and I also named it "city" in the Zip Code column, and gave a value of 0 so that it is an empty shape.  *** NOTE:  The "city" shape is not really "empty" it's just filled with a very light colors which affects the true colors of the underlying tiles that overlap with the "city" shape.  I still cannot figure out how to truly make an "empty" shape, so if anyone knows, please answer.

I also added a .update_traces and identified line marker_line_widths for each geometry and made the line width larger for only the city limit geometry.

Here's what it looks like (I also added some other Zip Code geometries here to better illustrate the idea):

[image: city outline]

UPDATE:  I found another post about how to add just the outlines of shapes in a Plotly Express choropleth map, and it worked for me.  [Adding geopandas boundary plot to plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880787/adding-geopandas-boundary-plot-to-plotly)